# How should I implement Google Signin in React (with Express backend)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Previously I implement google login using passport, I can implement this because I use ejs rendering engine in the frontend

But I just migrated and split the frontend and the backend, now the frontend is using reactjs and the backend is express, I use the express backend as api service

The question is, what is the best way to achive google signin with react frontend?

---

One way that come to my mind is, get the access token in react then send it to backend, and use the access token to get the user profile. But, I don't know how to implement this

Comment: You can do this by putting your token into HTTP header whenever you need authentications, but I can't not give you a full details because I don't know your architecture and state management.